# Very slow writing BLOB to Oracle DB using Python cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have a very simple Python application (using cx_Oracle) that is writing a BLOB to an Oracle database, but it is painfully slow when writing large files.  My application first downloads an image file from another system using a a SOAP API, and it downloads in a matter of a second or two. However, writing files to the DB of say 100k in size, takes a second or two, but a file of 1.5MB takes just over 1 minute.

My SQL is :-

INSERT INTO my_data (doc_id,doc_content) VALUES (:blobid, :blobdata), blobid=id_variable, blobdata=blob_variable

Is there a reason it's taking so long? Can I speed it up? It oughtn't take more than a few seconds I'd have thought?

(Disclaimer!  I have never used cx_Oracle or indeed Oracle itself ever before, I am comparing performance to Postgres which I have used for this kind of thing, and whose performance is infinitely better.)

The full code block is here :-

```
def upload_docs(doc,blob,conn):
    sql="INSERT INTO my_data (doc_id,doc_content) VALUES (:dociddata, :blobdata)"
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql, dociddata=doc, blobdata=blob)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user="Myuser", password="MyPassword",dsn="ocm.server.here.com:1527/some_name",encoding="UTF-8")
doc_csv = "/tmp/document_list.csv"
csv_file=open(doc_csv, 'r')

for line in csv_file:
splitLineArray = line.split(',')
documentId = splitLineArray[17]

#Pull document down from SOAP API
    documentData = (client.service.getDocument(int(documentId)))        
    upload_docs(documentId, documentData, conn)
```

Comment: This is most likely going to require tuning of the database infrastructure (storage, memory, etc.). You won't be able to do anything from within the application code. Get with your DBA to do a performance analysis and work out a solution.

Comment: The cx_Oracle documentation has a section on [tuning](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html), [using CLOBs and BLOBs](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html), and [LOBs](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/lob.html) in general. You might find something helpful there. But yes, you will probably need to tune the DB side - among other things maybe look at whether the BLOB column is cached. Your DBA will be in a better position to advise for your specific circumstances.

Comment: Thanks. It seems odd because I can write a 500KB file in 1 second, yet a 1.5MB takes 1 minute. i.e. the increase in time is not linear, so I doubt it's a tuning thing. It's more likely there is a threshold over which Oracle handles the data differently?

Comment: Share the full code block, in particular the code that populates the values for id_variable and blob_variable. If you are using temporary LOBs you will notice SIGNIFICANT slowdowns. I ams suspecting that is the issue but need confirmation.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the original post to include all the relevant lines.

Comment: One inefficiency is that you are using a loop over `execute()` instead of calling `executemany()`, see the cx_Oracle doc [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html)  And you're committing each row - is that really needed?  How big are the blobs?  How do you know the performance slowness isn't in the SOAP call?

Comment: Hi Christopher, I'll explore those options, thanks. I know the delay isn't the SOAP call as I had inserted lines in the code giving me a timestamp before and after the SOAP call, and before and after the DB write. This showed the SOAP call was almost instant, whereas the DB write was where the delay is.

Comment: So, I have now established it takes (less than) 1 second to write any file up to 750KB in size to the DB, then files that are 750KB to 1.5MB take 26 seconds, and files from 1.5MB to 2.25MB take 52 seconds.   So it appears there is some throttling going on somewhere adding 26 seconds per 750KB of data.

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't quite resolved this, I can now confirm the issue is *not* with cx_Oracle nor is it an issue with the database itself.  I am (or rather, was) connecting to the DB through Oracle Connection Manager, which was causing the delays. When I connect direct to the DB I can write large blobs in around a second. so the issue is definitely with OCM.